# Change color of readfile text output

Tags: php, html, css, colors, readfile

I have a very simple php script, of which is made to read the content of a file and then print it out on the site, using the method "readfile();" Here below you can see my code.

```
<?php
$readThisFile = './myFile.txt';

readfile($readThisFile);
?>
```

Now my question is whether it is possible to change the color of the text outcome, of which is visible on the website page. To give an example, once the php method has run and read my file and it outputs "hello world" on the site, because that is whats inside. Then the output is in black like any regular text, I was wondering whether it is possible to change that outcome to white or alike so that it is "invisible" on a white page.

I have seen it is possible to do this if the content which is on the site is "echoed" and not "read" like below here.

```
<?php
echo '<span style="color:white; align:center;">Hello World!</span>';
?>
```

But if that is possible to do with "readfile();" as well, I am not completely sure how I would implement it.

Comment: well sure you can, what's not working? you can start by opening the file, place the first `<span>`, then the file open then close the `</span>`, that should work, I've done it before. Go ahead a give it a whirl.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Alright, thank you very much I will look into it. It wasn't because anything wasn't working I just weren't completely sure of how to place the different elements within the script.

Comment: anytime ............ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```
<?php
$readThisFile = './myFile.txt';
echo `<span style="color:white; align:center;">`
readfile($readThisFile);
echo '</span>';
?>
```

Put the read text inside other element :)

Comment: Your input is very much appreciated, I ended up just including the php within an html setup so that I could have it as a div and then change the color of the div.

Comment: yeah, but it might not work sometimes because of security reasons, but I'm glad you found a solution :) Cheers